# specific pattern search in gvim

Tags: search, vim

I need to do a case sensitive search in gvim.
The pattern that I want to search looks something like:

For ex:
tABCD_EFGH_IJKL

Here the first alphabet 't' is a permanent character, after which the word starts with a capital letter (any alphabet).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
t[A-Z]{4}_[A-Z]{4}_[A-Z]{4}
```

To understand it, let's break it down.

```
t       "t"
[A-Z]   Any uppercase letter (from A to Z)...
{4}      ...4 times
_       Underscore
[A-Z]   Any uppercase letter (from A to Z)...
{4}      ...4 times
_       Underscore
[A-Z]   Any uppercase letter (from A to Z)...
{4}      ...4 times
```

To search with a regex in vim, hit `/` (forward slash) in Insert mode, type the pattern, then press Enter.

Comment: `[A-Z]` can be reduced to the character class `\u` (all upper case letters)